# How to connect a large number of multi-throw switches efficiently?

Tags: switches, charlieplexing

I have a number of 7 pole single throw switches that I need to connect together in some sort of grid configuration to a microcontroller, while minimizing the number of pins on the micro and the number of diodes/other elements I need.

The controller needs to be able to uniquely distinguish each switch regardless of how many of them are open or closed at a given time; presently there are 17 different switches.

I also do want to have some degree of redundancy on the mechanism - it is possible that one or two of the switch's poles might fail to make contact and remain open. (The other failure, accidental closure, is not an issue.) Ideally I would like to allow for up to two failures per switch without compromising the ability to register each input.

I have considered a few conventional methods:
With a conventional switch matrix, \$n\$ pins gets you \$(\frac{n}{2})^2\$ switches and needs \$(\frac{n}{2})^2\$ diodes.
Charlieplexing the switches would increase this to \$n^2 - n\$ switches while reducing the number of diodes to just \$n\$.

Both these have the advantage that I can just combine all the poles together and get my redundancy there. However, I would guess there might be a clever way to connect them taking advantage of the multiple poles to reduce or possibly eliminate the need for extra diodes.

How can I take advantage of the multiple poles to reduce the number of needed diodes while still maintaining some level of redundancy in the switch network?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmgb2I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Since accidental contact closure is not an issue the switch contacts can simply be wired in parallel for redundancy.*

Using this arrangement any multiplexed configuration including charlieplexing can be used. I don't think you can use less than one diode per switch except for switch 17 (4 x 4 + 1) as it may be on it's own dedicated pin. That makes 16 diodes the minimum.

Comment: I already mentioned this exact configuration in my question.

Comment: I read it twice before I answered. Schematics are better than words. This uses one diode per switch. Are you asking to improve on that?

Comment: I already have a way to do this with \$\lceil\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4 k+1}+\frac{1}{2}\rceil\$ diodes and \$\lceil\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4 k+1}+\frac{1}{2}\rceil\$ pins just with putting the switches in parallel. I am trying to do better than that.

Comment: What's "k"? Add a schematic to your question. Even if you don't get a decent answer it may help someone else.